# Finding a Function in a website

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function or number of functions that are running at a certain time during each day which is bringing the site down. What is easiest way to search through my thousands of custom and default functions which come with Wordpress so that I can reduce the manual time on my end to find these errant functions?

Comment: Check the crontab, with `crontab -l`; the scripts that are running might be there.

Comment: seems that isn't showing me what i am searching for. that tells me what is running at 6am EST, and our site is not going offline/online at that time so I am going to need to find these functions within the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few ways to tackle this

1. **mysql** - enable mysql slow query logging
2. **apache** - enable mod_status with `ExtendedStatus On`, and prepare a crontab to log the apache process around 6am
3. **linux** - use another crontab to log activity captured by `ps afx` during that 6am time span

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use http://www.php.net/debug_backtrace (together with http://www.php.net/set_error_handler )to implement some logging.